# visual studio 2019 installer setup templates missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Where are located ? I do not see
Following a tutorial here I meed to:
Add > New Project > Setup and Deployment Projects > Setup Wizard
but on my vs 2019 there are no templates for setup

Where can I get from, how to install to vs2019

Answer (score 11):

According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#add-items-to-the-project

Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects

in Visual Studio, choose Extensions > Manage Extensions. Under the Extensions and Updates dialog, select the Online tab and type Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects in the search box. Press Enter, select Microsoft Visual Studio  Installer Projects, and click Download. Choose to run and install the extension, then restart Visual Studio.